# client PC cannot connect to server PC Mysql

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I have 3 PCs - 1,2,3

PC 1 has database installed.

2nd PC can connect to  1st PC's Mysql -no problem.

while setting up same for 3rd PC its not working. 3rd PC cannot connect to 1st PC's Mysql using same host,user,password as used by 2nd PC.3rd PC gets Ping response with the Host.

All these PC's are connected through same network .Can anyone please suggest any solution ?

Comment: Please, show the error message.

Comment: Can't connect to mysql server '[given Host]' (10060)

Answer (score 0):

The error 10060 means that you **are not allowed** to access the web server remotely. Therefore

1. Make sure that you are using the same parameters of your connections on PC2 and PC3.
2. Use the `%` wildcard for the host part of the user account to allow connect from any host (see [Adding User Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html) article).

Please, see [Solution to Connecting remotely when you get Error 10060](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,239961) post for details.